# What to do with quiestion that would be "too localized" in previous stackexchange build?

Tags: support

Like [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77268/twitter-block-2-0-widget-not-showing-tweets/77272) - data provided by original author shows it's not general problem or issue, it's just something that needs to be debugged for him, on his site. What to do with problems like that now, when "too localized" is gone? [Meta Stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) suggests closing as off-topic, but we don't have that off-topic reason listed. Plus it's not exactly fair to incur off-topic penalties when person who asked legitimately believed (and had reasons to believe) her question is on topic one.

Comment: We don't have our [Custom Off-Topic Reasons](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2477/custom-off-topic-reasons-for-drupal-anwers) fully decided/committed yet. This would actually be a good candidate for an answer to that question if you have a suggestion for the text. Meanwhile I'll ping the other mods and see what we're doing about getting those custom reasons in...

Comment: Good point, why not as an answer? Anyway, added there. I'd be glad if you would take a look, maybe edit it if needed.

Comment: Read through the discussions on Too Localized on MSO, and in the blog post about the on-hold change.  Too Localized really meant that the question would be of no use to anytime at any point in the future.  I would say that this particular question would be of use to future visitors (assuming it had a proper answer...), as the third-party cookie thing isn't obvious.  I have dealt with this problem with clients before.

Comment: @MPD I didn't say I'm sure this one should be closed, only that I think it would be good to vote. Anyway it was just an example and my concern was of general nature.

Comment: I am closing this question, since there is a debate already in the other question.